# Suggestions for consolidation of old Linksys routers

Tags: firewall, router

I have a very simple small business network that I set up about 10 years ago using a pair of Linksys routers.  Over the past couple of years, the routers have become increasingly unstable as the amount of network traffic has increased.  There has not been a firmware update for these devices for over half a decade, so it's time for them to go.

Here is the network architecture

```
                                WAN IP          192.168.1.4  192.168.4.1 
 Internet <------> DSL Modem <---------> Linksys A <--------------> Public Wireless AP (WDS)
                                           ^ ^
                                           | | 192.168.1.2  192.168.2.1
                                           | +------------------> Second Public Wireless AP
                                           |
                                           | 192.168.1.3   192.168.3.1
                                           +---------------------> Linksys B (Intranet) <---> Switch
```

All of the intranet devices get IP address via DHCP in the 192.168.3.1/24 subnet.  All of the public access occurs on the 192.168.2.1/24 and 192.168.4.1/24 subnets. The Linksys A router is configured to block traffic between the public and provate subnets.  It is also set to forward SSH connections from the WAN to the 192.168.3.x subnet.

I would like to replace the Linksys A and Linksys B devices with a single device that allows the same configurations.

I am currently considering either the [Netgear FVS318G](http://www.netgear.com/business/products/security/wired-VPN-firewalls/FVS318G.aspx) or the [D-Link DSR-250](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/security/services-routers/dsr-250-unified-services-router).  I appears that both can be picked up for $100 - $150, which is right in my ideal budget.

Will either of these devices handle this kind of network configuration?  Is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

Also, I have a lot of the wireless access points running as dd-wrt devices in a WDS configuration, so I'm not opposed to buying a different device and flashing with an alternative firmware.

**Edit**

Found some information that the FVS318G does not support VLAN or Jumbo Frames.  In addition, the default firmware only allows two internal subnets (DMZ on port 8, LAN on parts 1 - 7).  I think that will eliminate it from consideration.

**Followup**

I ended up purchasing a [Routerboard 750](http://routerboard.com/RB750).  Very happy with the results so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration is not that complex.  You really don't *need* "prosumer" NAT router/firewall boxes if you don't want them.

What you ***DO*** need is proper isolation of your "public" and "intranet" networks -- you don't really have that here (Public devices can't hit your intranet's internal IPs, but they ***can*** see all of its traffic, and your intranet can hit public network's IPs -- that leaves you open to man-in-the-middle attacks).

---

My recommendation for you would be *real* firewall solution.
Commercial products exist from Juniper and Cisco, but you could do it with a spare commodity computer and [pfSense](http://pfsense.org) too if you're willing to support the solution yourself.

You would need three NICs (or two NICs and VLAN-capable hardware on the inside), and your end network should look something like this:

```
[Internet]----[MODEM]----[Firewall]-------(Public network switch & Devices)
                             |
                              ------------(Intranet switch & Devices)
```

With the firewall configured to prevent traffic from the Public and Intranet networks from mixing (implemented as separate security zones).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was leaning toward a prosumer device because I needed enough gigabit ports for all the intranet devices and because I thought that a simpler device might not be able be to be configured to segregate and route traffic per port.  A Cisco or Juniper device is overkill.

Comment: Also, wrt network isolation, the public and intranet are isolated.  These are not wireless Linksys boxes in the diagrams -- the access points are separate devices on their respective subnets, so there is no opportunity for any devices on the .2 or .4 subnets to see .3 subnet traffic.  I verified that with wireshark (ethereal back then) when I initially set up the network.